# MySQL Pivot with substitutions

Tags: mysql, group-by, pivot-table

I am trying to take entries from a Forms Plugin and reformat the results into a more usable format for front end viewing.  I believe that I can do this with a pivot but I can not figure it out from the examples provided.  As a Side note the datatbase includes entries from a number of different forms so I meed to be able to identify only the field_id values that are important for the query.

Current Data format

```
| entry-id | field_id |  slug  |  value  |
|   1      | fld_123  | First  |  Bob    |
|   1      | fld_234  | Last   | Smith   |
|   1      | fld_334  | Park   |Grand Can|
|   2      | fld_123  | First  | Mike    |
|   2      | fld_234  | Last   | Davis   |
|   2      | fld_334  | Park   |Grand Can|
```

The end result that I am looking for is:

```
|entry_ID  | First   |  Last  | park     
|  1       | Bob     | Smith  | Grand Can|
| 2        | Mike    | Davis  | Grand Can|
```

Please forgive the formatting of the entry I'm still figuring this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pivot your data like this:

```
SELECT entry_id, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(IF(slug='First', value,'') SEPARATOR '') AS first,
  GROUP_CONCAT(IF(slug='Last', value,'') SEPARATOR '') AS last,
  GROUP_CONCAT(IF(slug='Park', value,'') SEPARATOR '') AS park 
FROM tablename
GROUP BY entry_id;
```

NOTE: If the slug entries are unknown it's a bit more tricky and another type of query is needed. It's not a good idea to use hyphen in table or column names, so I use `entry_id` in this example instead of `entry-id`

Here you have the example in sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a03165/1/0

If you need to query by value, you could use a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT entry_id, field_id,
     GROUP_CONCAT(IF(slug='First', value,'') SEPARATOR '') AS first,
     GROUP_CONCAT(IF(slug='Last', value,'') SEPARATOR '') AS last,
     GROUP_CONCAT(IF(slug='Park', value,'') SEPARATOR '') AS park 
  FROM tablename
  GROUP BY entry_id) AS rows
WHERE first = '' OR park = '';
```

sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cef544/3/0

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and we are close the table is formatted correctly but the Values in the First , Last and Park are all empty.  Instead of using SLUG, can I use fld_1234?  The way that the Form tool populated the table the Slug is used in multiple forms with different IDs?

Comment: Michael,
I figured out my mistake and yoru solution works perfectly.  I do have one final issue tht I hope you can help me with.  Can we not display entry_id rows is slug='First', Value is blank or NULL?

Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Nice to hear it worked for you. Could you please accept the answer?
You could ask a new question if you have any further issues. It works fine also with empty or NULL values: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cef544/1/0

Comment: And if you need to query by value, you could use a subquery: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cef544/3/0

Answer (score 0):

Michael,
Thank you for your help, your suggestion solved the problem I was having.  Here it the actual query I was working with.

SELECT entry_id,

GROUP_CONCAT(IF(field_id='fld_5076430', value,'') SEPARATOR '') AS user,

GROUP_CONCAT(IF(field_id='fld_8768091', value,'') SEPARATOR '') AS first,

GROUP_CONCAT(IF(field_id='fld_9970286', value,'') SEPARATOR '') AS last,

GROUP_CONCAT(IF(field_id='fld_6009157', value,'') SEPARATOR '') AS date,

GROUP_CONCAT(IF(field_id='fld_5105414', value,'') SEPARATOR '') AS event,

GROUP_CONCAT(IF(field_id='fld_7723931', value,'') SEPARATOR '') AS unit,

GROUP_CONCAT(IF(field_id='fld_1521970', value,'') SEPARATOR '') AS work,

GROUP_CONCAT(IF(field_id='fld_4590434', value,'') SEPARATOR '') AS hours

FROM  kcdte_cf_form_entry_values

GROUP BY entry_id;

Comment: Glad it worked. Please accept the answer and upvote if you found it useful: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Comment: Michael,Thank you for your assistance.  One last issue, I need to format the AS date colum in a true DATE format of mm-dd-yy.

Comment: Please ask a new question for further assistance. In MySQL you could use `DATE_FORMAT(date_column, "%m-%d-%Y")`

Comment: I have added an answer to your other question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49154609/1363190