# Converting "Values" from long text column to date format

Tags: mysql

The MySQL table has a longtext Column that houses a number of different entries of different formats. I would like to convert a particular type of entries into a standard date format of mm-dd-yy.

Here is the query that I am using to pivot the table and pull out just the values that I need.  The AS date values are the ones that I am trying to convert to a date.  I am fairly sure I just need to use date_format(%m-%d-%y) but I am not sure how and where to enter it.

SELECT * FROM (
SELECT entry_id,

GROUP_CONCAT(IF(field_id='fld_5076430', value,'') SEPARATOR '') AS user,

GROUP_CONCAT(IF(field_id='fld_8768091', value,'') SEPARATOR '') AS first,

GROUP_CONCAT(IF(field_id='fld_9970286', value,'') SEPARATOR '') AS last,

GROUP_CONCAT(IF(field_id='fld_6009157', value,'') SEPARATOR '') AS date,

GROUP_CONCAT(IF(field_id='fld_5105414', value,'') SEPARATOR '') AS event,

GROUP_CONCAT(IF(field_id='fld_7723931', value,'') SEPARATOR '') AS unit,

GROUP_CONCAT(IF(field_id='fld_1521970', value,'') SEPARATOR '') AS work,

GROUP_CONCAT(IF(field_id='fld_4590434', value,'') SEPARATOR '') AS hours

FROM  kcdte_cf_form_entry_values

GROUP BY entry_id) AS rows
WHERE hours > '' AND last > '';

I would like to thank Michael K from this group for his help in getting me where I am on this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using the MySQL-function `STR_TO_DATE()` to convert your strings to date format:

```
STR_TO_DATE(GROUP_CONCAT(IF(field_id='fld_6009157', value,'') SEPARATOR ''), '%m-%d-%Y') AS date,
```

If you are planning to store the dates in a MySQL-database with the datatype `date` you should use the format `YYYY-mm-dd` achieved with `'%Y-%m-%d'` instead of `'%m-%d-%Y'` in the above example.